# How to replace data in a specific row jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi everyone I want to replace data inside the row depending upon the row number. The code I have posted traverses through the rows in the table, counts the row-indexes and matches them with the required row. If condition gets true the data should be replaced in that row. *I have edited the question*

I don't know what should I use to replace the data?

I have tried .innerHTML, .replaceWith() but they do not give me the required thing.

```
$('table#table-mytable tr').each(function(){
  var row_required = tag[tag.length-2];
  console.log('this is row_required: '+row_required);
  var row = $(this).index()+1;
  console.log('this is row: '+row);
  if(row==row_required) {
     (What should I enter here)
  }
});
```

I want replace with something like:
      replaceWith('td colspan="2" input type="text" name="input_" class="input_" id="input_" value="' + input_tag + '" placeholder="Enter Label" /td>')?

Comment: You are looping the rows. A row however doesn't have content. It has cells (`<td>`) which contain the content. So you are looking for something like `row.find('td').html('The new text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `html()` (amongst other methods) to replace the contents of the `tr`. Also note that you don't need to loop at all. If you know the index you can select it directly using `eq()`:

```js
var row_required = 1;
$('#table-mytable tr').eq(row_required).html('<td>Bar</td>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```